# How to overload SharePoint FileCheckIn operation in VSTO

Tags: c#, vba, sharepoint, ms-word, vsto

Can anyone overload the SharePoint FileCheckIn operation using VSTO?
I think Microsoft may have *forgotten* to implement it (and a number of other operations)

In my Ribbon XML I add the following three commands:

```
<commands>
  <command idMso="FileCheckIn" onAction="FileCheckIn_Click"/>
  <command idMso="FileCheckOut" onAction="FileCheckOut_Click"/>
  <command idMso="FileCheckOutDiscard" onAction="FileCheckOutDiscard_Click"/>
</commands>
```

With the corresponding C# callbacks:

```
    public void FileCheckIn_Click(Office.IRibbonControl control, ref bool cancelDefault)
    { cancelDefault = false; /*Does not work*/ }

    public void FileCheckOut_Click(Office.IRibbonControl control, ref bool cancelDefault)
    { cancelDefault = false; /* Works! */ }

    public void FileCheckOutDiscard_Click(Office.IRibbonControl control, ref bool cancelDefault)
    { cancelDefault = false; /*Does not work*/ }
```

Interestingly, FileCheckOut works fine, but FileCheckIn and FileCheckOutDiscard do not.
Strangely, I had more success in VBA:

```
Public Sub FileCheckIn()
    MsgBox "I work!"
End Sub
Public Sub FileCheckOut()
    MsgBox "I work!"
End Sub
Public Sub FileCheckOutDiscard()
    MsgBox "I don't.."
End Sub
```

Hopefully I've made a mistake somewhere along the way. Help appreciated.
As far as I can see this functionality has been broken in Office 2007 and Office 2010. I haven't tested Office 2013 yet.

--Edit--
I've completed some testing in Office 2013. Even worse, I'm afraid:

- None of the C# callbacks fire when a CheckIn/CheckOut/Discard is
  performed in the UI
- Only the FileCheckIn VBA method works
- Interestingly, the following line of code causes the CheckIn C#
  callback to fire:

  this.Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso("FileCheckIn");

I guess it's possible that the UI/Backstage changes in Office 2013 changed the names of the VBA routines.